# Filtering text input JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I'm looking for filtering text input the combo box is working but the text box is working into age. I want is to filter the name but I don`t have a idea to do.

Combo box is for age and the text field is for name.

**HTML**

all age
    16
    18
    20

```
<input />
 <table class="AvailableGroupLab availGrpLabs avalLabs">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
     </thead>
<tbody>

    <tr>
        <td><span>wewe</span>

        </td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Melvin</span>

        </td>
        <td>18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>Marvin</span>

        </td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <td><span>wewex</span>

        </td>
        <td>20</td>
    </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
function filter(element) {

         var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tbody tr').hide();
        var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');  
        var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
            return regexp.test($(this).find('td:last-child').text())
        }).show();
        $trs.not($valid).hide()

}

$('input, select').on('keyup change', function () {   
    if($(this).val() !== ""){
       filter(this);  
     } else{
        $('.AvailableGroupLab tbody tr').show();
    }

})
```

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/NpLDn/)

Comment: this is my sample http://jsfiddle.net/NpLDn/

Comment: It is always better to add code to your question mate. Also, the fiddle link should be put in your question :)

Comment: this is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NpLDn/2/

Comment: I did see your fiddle link above. What I said was, it is better to edit question and put the link in it than in comments :)

Comment: ow i see is now it the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to your code.Try this:

```
function filter(element) {

         var $trs = $('.AvailableGroupLab tbody tr').hide();
        var regexp = new RegExp($(element).val(), 'i');  
        var $valid = $trs.filter(function () {
            return isNaN($(element).val())?regexp.test($(this).find('td:first-child span').text()):regexp.test($(this).find('td:last-child').text());
        }).show();
        $trs.not($valid).hide()

}

$('input, select').on('keyup change', function () {   
    if($(this).val() !== ""){
       filter(this);  
     } else{
        $('.AvailableGroupLab tbody tr').show();
    }

})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NpLDn/1/

New JSFiddle(with filter): http://jsfiddle.net/NpLDn/4/

Comment: this is greate sir. but when i search the age of 20. then i search the name with "we". why the wewe age of 16 showed? i want the filter age 20 only can i filter :) last question :)

Comment: @wewe: I have made some changes,pls have a look at it.